# Running one line silently

Tags: vbscript, windows-scripting

I have an obfuscation method i use when creating batch scripts, just add the bytes `FF` and `FE` to the start of the file, and your text editor will give you chineese characters. I tried this in vbs, but it throws an error and the script terminates. theese 2 bytes have to be the first thing in the text file, otherwise it wont work, is there any way to comment a line from behind, or silence output like `>nul 2>nul` in Batch?

Comment: What obfuscation? Every decent text editor will recognize the [UTF16-LE byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Also why should `2>&1>NUL` not work in batch?

Comment: No, >nul 2>nul works alright in batch, ibwas asking if there was a way to achieve something similar in VBscript. And i'm not concerned about better text editors, it only has to work for notepad (on windows)

Comment: In vbs you can comment with `' comment` or ': rem comment' .Why the batch-file tag?

Comment: Because the first twobbytes have to be FF FE, if you put a single quote or a rem, then it doesnt display in different encoding

Comment: @LotPings It's *because* decent editors pick up the BOM that they will display the rest of the file as [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). And for the same reason decent runtime environments will fail to run the script, because they're reading the file as UTF-16 LE (as instructed by the BOM) and can't recognize the mojibake.

Comment: @SomeGuy If you really need to hide your code (why?) I recommend you switch to a compiled language. You can't really hide code with nterpreted languages.